# How to compare the column with textbox in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I wish to ask, how could I compare my "Quantity to Redeem" and "Quantity Available" when I key in value in textbox?

Example, in My gridview,I key in "2" in textbox, but the available quantity only "1".So I wish to display error shows that quantity not enough. 
My validation only will done on the last row of the gridview

(I apologize for my messy coding skill and I could not post image due to low reputation,will screenshot in comment)

My button click

```
Dim row As GridViewRow
    Dim strAvailable As String
    Dim strRedeem As String

    For Each row In GridView1.Rows
        ' write ur DB process code here
        strAvailable = CType(row.Cells(4).FindControl("lblAvailable"),Label).Text
        strRedeem = CType(row.Cells(5).FindControl("txtRedeem"), TextBox).Text

        If strRedeem > strAvailable Then
            lblMessage.Text = "Quantity not enough"
            btnPrint.Visible = False

        Else
            lblMessage.Text = "Enough Quantity"
            btnPrint.Visible = True
        End If
    Next
end sub
```

Comment: What code gives the error "input string was not in correct format". This error normally appears when you try to parse some type to other.

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/6tsi1dxzn/  
this is the error when I try to add in "testing"

Comment: Ok you need to write like this lblMessage.Text = "Total number: " + totalA.ToString();

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for helping me to solve this problem :)
Do u have any clue for the Quantity validation?

Comment: What you want to do in validation ?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/za0y3lumb/
this screenshot example show program run normally

http://postimg.org/image/dklaiqb6b/
this screenshot run normally but the logic is wrong,my first row data does not have enough quantity but it still show "enough quantity" in my label,i had made some changes in button click

Comment: You are comparing strings you should convert it to int and than compare it.

Comment: This is because loop will iterate on each row and only last row result will be considered as text of label is over written every time loop executes so result will be of last row.

Comment: if any row has insufficient quantity and you want it to stop than just break the loop with break statement; And if you want to show it at end of loop than you need to have a variable in which you will store that if quantity is insufficeint or not.

Comment: yup,i just added exit for to stop the loop, thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `ToString()` method when assigning value to textbox because your are concatenating `string and int` and assigning it to `Text` property of textbox or label which expects a `string`.

```
lblMessage.Text = "Total number: " + totalA.ToString();
```

You are comparing `two strings` but you need to compare two `int variables` so you need to convert `string to int`.

```
Dim row As GridViewRow
Dim strAvailable As Integer
Dim strRedeem As Integer

For Each row In GridView1.Rows
     //write ur DB process code here
    strAvailable = CType(CType(row.Cells(4).FindControl("lblAvailable"),Label).Text,int);
    strRedeem =CType(CType(row.Cells(5).FindControl("txtRedeem"), TextBox).Text,int);

    If strRedeem > strAvailable Then
        lblMessage.Text = "Quantity not enough"
        btnPrint.Visible = False

    Else
        lblMessage.Text = "Enough Quantity"
        btnPrint.Visible = True
    End If
Next
```

end sub

**Note** I don't know exact syntax of VB so please forgive me for this and correct it if it is not correct.